# MySQL sub query with multiple columns

Tags: mysql

After some research I now understand I cannot return multiple columns from a subquery. What can I do instead?

```
 SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `id` IN (SELECT `id1`, `id2` FROM `ids` WHERE `location` = 1)
```

The result is `#1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: You can provide proper create and insert statements, and a corresponding desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select users.* 
  from users 
    join ids 
   on users.id IN(ids.id1, ids.id2)
   and ids.location = 1;
```

Comment: The use of archaic query syntax (ca. 1992) is to be discouraged.

Comment: @Strawberry : Updated it . Is it fine now?

Comment: It's not really a cross join, but MySQL doesn't know the difference, so ok. Well, I might tweak it...

Comment: @Strawberry : For the clarification, the join by default means the Inner Join, right? Also inner join with on and cross join with where is no different in mysql even in terms of performance. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: MySQL only distinguishes between OUTER JOINS (of which there are two varieties) and 'NON-OUTER' JOINS. It accepts keywords like INNER and CROSS, but, in practice it's the presence or otherwise of an ON clause that determines the behaviour of the NON-OUTER JOIN. By contrast an OUTER JOIN (whether LEFT or RIGHT) must always have an ON clause (although the OUTER keyword itself is optional). Finally, while RIGHT JOINs are perfectly valid, in practice no one ever uses them. Every RIGHT JOIN has a logically identical LEFT JOIN, and LEFT JOINs are more intuitive. I'll get my coat.